# Firebase When uploading file Error: AppCheck: AppCheck is being used before activate()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am currently constructing a file upload to my firebase account. But when I do this, I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: AppCheck: AppCheck is being used before activate() is called for FirebaseApp [DEFAULT]. Please make sure you call activate() before instantiating other Firebase services. (appCheck/use-before-activation).

What I've done so far:

1. I disabled authentication rules for development purposes. I set rules into this

   ```
    rules_version = '2';
    service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != true;
        }
      }
    }
   ```
2. I installed firebase into my Vue Cli App using the command:

   ```js
   npm install --save firebase
   ```
3. Initialized firebase in my App using the following:

   ```js
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import "firebase/analytics";
    import "firebase/storage";
    import 'animate.css';

    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "*API KEY*",
      authDomain: "lgu-cantilan-hrms.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "lgu-cantilan-hrms",
      storageBucket: "lgu-cantilan-hrms.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "*SENDER ID*",
      appId: "*APP ID*",
      measurementId: "*G-8ZQZT5BCZQ*"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
   ```
4. Had this setup in my upload component:

   ```html
    <template>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="800">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            elevation=""
            color="blue white--text"
            class="ml-10"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            @click="dialog = true"
            ><v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-file-outline</v-icon>View Files</v-btn
          >
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-toolbar color="red" dark>
            <span class="headline mr-2">Files</span>
            <span class="ml-10">
              {{ employee.last_name }}, {{ employee.first_name }}'s Files</span
            >
          </v-toolbar>
          <v-card-text>
            <div class="pa-5">
              <span class="primary--text overline">Add A File</span>
              <div class="mb-5 mt-2">
                <input type="file" class="ml-2" @change="upload_file" />
                <v-btn small color="" @click="upload"> Submit</v-btn>
              </div>
              <v-divider> </v-divider>
              <Files />
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Files from "@/components/Files/Files.vue";
    import firebase from "firebase";
    export default {
      components: { Files },
      data() {
        return {
          dialog: false,
          employee: {},
          file_upload: null,
          uploadValue: 0,
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.employee = this.$store.state.user.user_view;
      },
      methods: {
        upload_file(e) {
          this.file_upload = e.target.files[0];
          console.log(this.file_upload);
          // this.picture_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.picture);
        },
        upload() {
          var storageRef = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(this.employee.first_name + "/" + this.file_upload.name);
          var task = storageRef.put(this.file_upload);
          // monitor progress
          task.on(
            "state_change",
            (snapshot) => {
              this.uploadValue =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error.message);
            }
          );

          // task.on("state_change",)
        },
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style></style>
   ```

But when I click the submit button, console gives me an error saying:
Uncaught (in promise):

> FirebaseError: AppCheck: AppCheck is being used before activate() is called for FirebaseApp [DEFAULT]. Please make sure you call activate() before instantiating other Firebase services. (appCheck/use-before-activation).

I don't have any idea what this error means. I followed the instructions in the documentation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. This is for reference. It was the import firebase from 'firebase' it should be import firebase from 'firebase/app' in my Vue component. Hope this thread helps other people.

Comment: I've got the same error and I'm importing firebase from 'firebase/app'. What the heck is Appcheck anyway? Is this part of the firebase SDK?

Comment: *firebaser here* It sounds like something broke in our latest SDK release. Good to hear that you found a workaround @JanMichael. We're working on an updated SDK release that won't require this workaround anymore.

Comment: And I just got a ping from a team mate that this should be fixed in version 8.6.1: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#8.6.1 Apologies for everyone who was affected by this misfire.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah after 5 hours of having no idea what the error message means. I just tried out possible actions and fortunately found it.

Comment: @Colin I also don't have any idea. I've been searching it last night and there's no thread or posts that have the same error as I have. So yeah it really is a pain in the ass.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, would you please share the steps required to upgrade Js SDK so we can overcome it? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The problem should be gone when using SDK version 8.6.1. Is that not the case for you @JuanGiacosa?

Comment: Like @FrankvanPuffelen said, the error was fixed after updating the firebase module.

Comment: I don't really know how to update the SDK version, but it stopped complaining by switching `firebase-functions` inside `package.json` from `ˆ3.13.2` to `3.13.2`

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 8.6.0 and had the same issue when trying to upload an image. Updating firebase to the latest version (at the time 8.6.5) fixed the issue for me.

to check your firebase version run `npm list firebase`

to update to the latest version run `npm update firebase`

afterwards, close the current running terminal if you have the app running and `npm start` again